# getting nulls after converting xml to table?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012-express

I am trying to convert my xml file into a table in sql server, but I am getting nulls after the  addresses tag. Where I am doing wrong.

Also have can I properly change the name of the column to not get this error:

"Duplicate column names are not allowed in result sets obtained through OPENQUERY and OPENROWSET. The column name "created" is a duplicate."

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/contacts/contact', 2) 
WITH 
(
.
.
.
.
.)
```

xml

```
    <contacts>
      <contact>
        <address></address>
        <sex nil="true"/>
        <marital-status-id nil="true"/>
        <letter-salutation nil="true"/>
        <first-name nil="true"/>
        <middle-name nil="true"/>
        <last-name nil="true"/>
        .
        .
        .
        <addresses>
          <address>
            <id></id>
            <is-primary>1</is-primary>
            <label></label>
            <street-1></street-1>
            .
            .
            .
          </address>
        </addresses>
        <phones>
          <phone>
            <id></id>
            <label>Phone</label>
            <digits></digits>
           .
           .
           .
          </phone>
          <phone>
            <id></id>
            <label></label>
            <digits></digits>
            .
            .
            .
          </phone>
        </phones>
        <emails>
          <email>
            <id></id>
            <is-primary>true</is-primary>
            .
            .
            .
          </email>
        </emails>
      </contact>
<contacts>
```

Comment: You didn't pasted the complete query, the SchemaDeclaration inside a WITH block is required to comment further.

Answer (score 0):

the information you give is not enough... Assuming your XML is successfully loaded into an XML variable you'll need something like this (attention: you end-tag in the given example is wrong, the "/" is missing):

Btw: You will not fill this "into a table". You will need 1:n-sub-tables for addresses, phones and emails.

The way you get the information out of the XML-sub-nodes is quite the same. Read about CROSS APPLY

```
;WITH MyXML_CTE AS
(
SELECT contact.oneContact.value('address[1]','varchar(max)') AS address
      ,contact.oneContact.value('sex[1]','varchar(max)') AS sex
      ,contact.oneContact.value('marital-status[1]','varchar(max)') AS [marital-status]
      ,contact.oneContact.value('letter-salutation[1]','varchar(max)') AS [letter-salutation]
      ,contact.oneContact.value('first-name[1]','varchar(max)') AS [first-name]
      ,contact.oneContact.value('middle-name[1]','varchar(max)') AS [middle-name]
      ,contact.oneContact.value('last-name[1]','varchar(max)') AS [last-name]
      ,contact.oneContact.query('addresses') AS addresses
      ,contact.oneContact.query('phones') AS phones   
      ,contact.oneContact.query('emails') AS emails   
FROM @contact.nodes('/contacts/contact') AS contact(oneContact)
)
SELECT * FROM MyXML_CTE
```

Comment: @erser, if this answer helped you, it would be kind of you to mark it as accepted and/or click to upvote.Thx!